# Why does int steps change?

Tags: c#, timer, int

i have a problem with my code :

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    int TimeCount;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
        TimeCount = 0;
        Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
    }

    private void TimerEventProcessor(Object sender, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        TimeCount = TimeCount + 1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        TimeCount = 0;
    }
```

At the first run, TimeCount will do steps well (1,2,3,4,5,....)

but if i button2 to stop, then button1 to restart, TimeCount steps will do (2,4,6,8,10,...)

and then if i repeat operation steps will do (3,6,9,....)

How to get my TimeCount int to correctly allways do (1,2,3,4,5,....) ?

Comment: How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with how you're using event handler delegates:

```
Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
```

This adds a new handler (`TimerEventProcessor`) to the list of delegate methods `Tick` holds. So on each tick, the event will loop through the registered handlers and call them each in turn.

If you add a method to `Tick` twice, it will get called twice. Add it three times, it will get called three times, and so on. Each time you click `button1` you add another handler to the list.

I suggest moving `Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);` to the load event (e.g. `Form_Load`) or to your constructor (`public Form1()`). You only need to register the handler *once*.

Alternatively, in button2, deregister the handler:

```
Timer1.Tick -= new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
```

Comment: Thanks John, exactly what i've missed !